# Infinite tensor product

Tags: operator-theory, tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose that $X$ is an infinite set and $A$ is a unital $C^*$-algebra. The tensor product $\bigotimes_X A$ is defined to be the closed linear span of $\bigotimes_{x\in X }a_x$, where $a_x\in A$ for all $x\in A$ and $a_x=1$ for all but finitely many $x\in X$.

I feel confused about the above definition. Is every element of
 $\otimes_X A$ the form of $a_1\otimes\cdots\otimes a_n \otimes 1\cdots \otimes 1\otimes\cdots$ for some $n$?

Comment: Every element can be written as a (possibly infinite) linear combination of such elements.

Comment: Note that your notation is problematic. The expression $a_1\otimes \cdots \otimes a_n \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots \otimes 1$ implies that we are taking a tensor product of finitely many elements. The expression $a_1\otimes \cdots \otimes a_n \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots$ is a bit better, but still implies that we are taking a tensor product of countably many elements.

Comment: In the case where your notation makes sense, i.e. when $X=\mathbb N$, it is not true that every element of $\bigotimes_{\mathbb N}A$ is a finite tensor product, as this would fail to be complete.  I'd recommend reviewing your reference material, thinking about your question a bit, then cleaning it up with an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X=\mathbb N$, the algebraic tensor product is the *span* of the elementary tensors $a_1\otimes\cdots\otimes a_n\otimes 1\otimes\cdots$. So sums of the form 
$$\tag1
\sum_{k=1}^m a_{k1}\otimes\cdots\otimes a_{kn}\otimes 1\otimes\cdots.
$$
The C$^*$-tensor product is the *closure* of the sets of elements of the form $(1)$. The key in defining the tensor product is the norm that you use. Depending on the C$^*$-algebra $A$, there could be more than one possible.

When $X$ is an arbitrary set, you need to write things more carefully (although the spirit is what was said above). A "tuple" indexed by $X$ is a function $f:X\to A$. In this case you can identity the elementary tensors with those maps $f:X\to A$ such that $f(x)=1$ for all by finitely many $x\in X$. Then to define the algbraic tensor product $\bigotimes_X A$ you take the formal span of all those functions and quotient by the subspace given by the tensor relations.